# Script python can't close connection to mysqldb when I stop it by keyboard nterrupt

Tags: python, mysql, connection

I have two script
Main.py 
Script1.py
main.py  execute script 1.py by os.system()
Scrip1 connect to mysqldb 
When i run main.py by command line and after I stop it by keyboardintterupt  script1.py can't close cmysql connection

Answer (score 0):

When you stop a script via the command line the script will stop wherever it is without executing any remaining code. This is wanted and normal!

Do not use the command line as a way to support code that is deployed and in commercial use!

You may look into destructors but those are executed only if your environment allows that to happen. 
Example:

```
__del__(self): #a destructor, it is called when the object dies
    clean_up() #but if the OS really wants to it might interrupt it
```

Therefore I strongly recommend to use a library which will handle this or build a system that you won't have to interrupt via the command line. Maybe consider a special thread for cleanup.